# Select inner HTML item in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I use CSS selectors to apply a style only to the inner item in a list. Example:

HTML fragment:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>Subitem 1</li>
      <li>Subitem 2</li>
      <li>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>Subitem 1.1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS fragment:

```
ul.list {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

What I need is to have a border **only** arround the "Subitem 1.1" string. The list is generated and it's not possible to add an extra class or id and as the list has no fixed depth it's not an option to specify an "ul > ul > ul.list" or similar selector.

Comment: How is Subitem 1 distinguishable from Subitem 1.1? Since the depth is not fixed how do you know which item needs that CSS applied?

Comment: This would be really easy if either you applied an extra class, CSS had parent combinators/pseudo-classes or nth-level descendant pseudo-classes, or `:not()` supported more than just simple selectors.

Comment: If the list has no fixed depth, do you want to select the last `ul` in the tree? e.g. it could just as easily be 1 level deep or 4?

Comment: The problem with this is that these lists are generated by PHP and JS is not an option due the requirements says it must work also with script disabled. Last option is modify PHP function (really ugly task) or use JS. Thanks in any case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you cannot do this with only CSS if it is not possible to use an Id or unique class. In this case I think jQuery is the way to go:

```
$("li").children().eq( $("li").children().length - 1 ).
  css('border', '1px solid red');
```

The idea is to use `eq()` to pinpoint the deepest child.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

> it's not an option to specify an "ul > ul > ul.list" or similar selector.

Why not? This, or adding a class, is the solution.

You've basically specified a requirement to identify an element, then rejected all the approaches that you could use to do so.

Comment: Well, I'm looking for something like :first-child pseudo-class that I've missed... :deepest-node perhaps? :)

Comment: There aren't any selectors I know that target the deepest descendants, only the immediate ones (`>`)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
li.list {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul >
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>
    <ul >
      <li>Subitem 1</li>
      <li>Subitem 2</li>
      <li>
        <ul >
          <li class="list">Subitem 1.1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I Hope This ma help you..

Answer (score 0):

JoseSantos is correct in that it can't be done with pure CSS. Here's how I'd do it in jQuery:

```
$("ul").each(function(){
    if ($(this).find("ul").length == 0)
        $(this).addClass("list");
});
```