# Use selector to get the inner child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to select the inner child (deepest) using css selectors. Se example below:

```
<div class='d1 view'>
    <div class='d2 view'>
        <div class='d3 view'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='d4 view'>
        <div class='d5 view'>
            <div class='d6 view'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The d1-d6 classes is just for simplifying my question.

I now want to select d3 and d6.
Note the list of children can be infinite. So is there a way to select - using css selectors -  the deepest child?

I made a [JSFiddle using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/dzxpP/2/)

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247888/css-selector-to-get-deepest-element-of-specific-class-in-the-html-tree

Comment: look on http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently with CSS there is no way to select the deepest child of a parent element. You'll have to resort to jQuery to solve this.

There are a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787924/select-deepest-child-in-jquery) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180583/select-inner-html-item-in-css) that cover this already.